# What is the syntax to finish off this /execute gamemode command? It's exactly like the Status Effect command that works

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I can give a player a status effect when they enter a certain area and remove it when they leave no problem, but when I try to do the same thing with the game mode, nothing happens. In my mind these are the same thing. I can get the game mode to change for everyone or one person when I flip a switch, but not in a certain area. See below. I’m running Forge for 1.16.4 and putting these commands in Repeating Command Blocks buried in the ground, in the area they affect.

Why does this NOT work:

```
execute if entity @p[x=94,y=50,z=85,dx=26,dy=33,dz=27] run gamemode adventure @p
```

When this does?

```
execute if entity @p[x=10020,y=80,z=10142,dx=30,dy=20,dz=43] run effect give @p minecraft:jump_boost 1 10 true
```

So much for minecraft’s “autofill guided prompts” which says it’s valid in like 10 different iterations, but then it just doesn’t do anything. It prompted me to put the `@p` at the end but I don't know why it's there and it won't let me add any target selector arguments to it, which makes me feel it's superfluous. I've tried adding:

```
as @p
```

and

```
at @p
```

to the front, and back, and still nothing. What am I missing or putting too much of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been testing that command and works perfectly fine. There is only one problem, the area of effect is inverted for the destination cords (I don't really know why). Try inverting destination cords, like this:

```
execute if entity @p[x=94,y=50,z=85,dx=-26,dy=33,dz=-27] run gamemode adventure @p
```

Comment: I think that you may be onto something... but I don't know what you mean by my coodinates are inverted, or "destination coords". There is only one set at it's the test area start point with a distance from that start point with the "d" attached. They are in xyz order as normal, and all you did was copy my coordinates from my other example, which are formatted the same.

Are you suggesting the change gamemode command just does not work at the ~10K coordinates I'm trying it with??

Comment: You were right, I had been standing the wrong direction at the second location and needed to put -100020 etc. but I don't know how you knew I should "invert it" and then you didn't quote the solution properly but it still shook my brain up to solve it so thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to say. I realized that after trying some times with your command, which had that ("-" symbol) issue. I'm gald it worked for you